# Protractor: Chrome failed to start - exited abnormally

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, protractor, specs

When i run my spec, it starts up Chrome and instantly opens another tab to the Chrome Settings page.  Totally clueless as to what is going on.  Here is the error message:

```
[11:38:54] I/direct - Using ChromeDriver directly...
[11:38:54] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[11:39:54] E/launcher - unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.26.436421 (6c1a3ab469ad86fd49c8d97ede4a6b96a49ca5f6),platform=Mac OS X 10.12.6 x86_64)
[11:39:54] E/launcher - WebDriverError: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.26.436421 (6c1a3ab469ad86fd49c8d97ede4a6b96a49ca5f6),platform=Mac OS X 10.12.6 x86_64)
        at WebDriverError 
 (/Users/hoseasteele/.nvm/versions/node/v4.8.4/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:27:10)
    at Object.checkLegacyResponse (/Users/hoseasteele/.nvm/versions/node/v4.8.4/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:639:15)
    at parseHttpResponse (/Users/hoseasteele/.nvm/versions/node/v4.8.4/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/http/index.js:538:13)
    at /Users/hoseasteele/.nvm/versions/node/v4.8.4/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/http/index.js:472:11
    at ManagedPromise.invokeCallback_ (/Users/hoseasteele/.nvm/versions/node/v4.8.4/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:1379:14)
    at TaskQueue.execute_ (/Users/hoseasteele/.nvm/versions/node/v4.8.4/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2913:14)
    at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (/Users/hoseasteele/.nvm/versions/node/v4.8.4/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2896:21)
    at /Users/hoseasteele/.nvm/versions/node/v4.8.4/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2820:25
    at /Users/hoseasteele/.nvm/versions/node/v4.8.4/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:639:7
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:438:9)
From: Task: WebDriver.createSession()
    at Function.createSession (/Users/hoseasteele/.nvm/versions/node/v4.8.4/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:329:24)
    at Driver (/Users/hoseasteele/.nvm/versions/node/v4.8.4/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/chrome.js:778:38)
    at Direct.getNewDriver (/Users/hoseasteele/.nvm/versions/node/v4.8.4/lib/node_modules/protractor/built/driverProviders/direct.js:68:26)
    at Runner.createBrowser (/Users/hoseasteele/.nvm/versions/node/v4.8.4/lib/node_modules/protractor/built/runner.js:190:43)
    at /Users/hoseasteele/.nvm/versions/node/v4.8.4/lib/node_modules/protractor/built/runner.js:264:30
    at _fulfilled (/Users/hoseasteele/.nvm/versions/node/v4.8.4/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:834:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/Users/hoseasteele/.nvm/versions/node/v4.8.4/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:863:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/Users/hoseasteele/.nvm/versions/node/v4.8.4/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:796:13)
    at /Users/hoseasteele/.nvm/versions/node/v4.8.4/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:556:49
    at runSingle (/Users/hoseasteele/.nvm/versions/node/v4.8.4/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:137:13)
[11:39:54] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 199
```

Comment: Try running `webdriver-manager update` first to update your drivers. Current chrome driver is 2.33, you are running 2.26. If problem persists, please edit your question to include your protractor config and relevant test spec.

Answer (score 0):

You are using old version of chrome driver. Update all drivers with

```
webdriver-manager update
```